# php replace multiple placeholders in text returns 1 element instead 2

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string and i want to return 2 placeholder in an array, how can i achieve that?

```
$text = 'is simply dummy text of the printing and [[file::aaa]] typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the [[file::bbb]] standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.';

if (preg_match("/\[\[.*\]\]/", $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: Try `.*?` for non-greedy. And use preg_match_all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trying something like this :

```
if (preg_match_all("/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/", $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[file::aaa]]
            [1] => [[file::bbb]]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => file::aaa
            [1] => file::bbb
        )

)
```